# Use filename insted of 'Download'

Tags: javascript, html, django, attachment

On my Django page I have a paragraph to download attached files:

```
{% for i in post.file_set.all %}<p class="article-content mt-2 mb-1"><strong>Attachment {{ forloop.counter }}: </strong><a href="{{i.file.url}}" >Download</a></p>{% endfor %}
```

How can I show File name insted of word 'Download'. Users don't know which file is which when downloading, in case of many files. Also, if extension is possible.

So, insted of:

```
Attachment: Download
```

I would like to have:

```
Attachment: image.png
```

Comment: `<a href="{{i.file.url}}">{{i.file.name}}</a>` or similar

Comment: It works exactly like inserting the URL into href though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `Download` with `{{i.file.name}}`

```
{% for i in post.file_set.all %}<p class="article-content mt-2 mb-1"><strong>Attachment {{ forloop.counter }}: </strong><a href="{{i.file.url}}" >{{i.file.name}}</a></p>{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not clear to OP that to Django's templating system, all the HTML is just arbitrary text, and that inserting the filename works exactly like inserting the url. Your answer should focus on that imo, instead of consist of just two lines of the very obvious answer. Useful for future readers and all that. (in my personal opinion, no answer should be posted here at all)

Comment: This works great. Just one remark. Now I see full url, is it possible to see just file name?
Attachment 1: PN_files/2022/02/14/file_name.xlsx
I would like:
Attachment 1: file_name.xlsx

Comment: @MarkoZg Did you replace Download with `{{i.file.url}}`? Or `{{i.file.name}}`?

Comment: I replaced 'Download' with i.file.name, like:
{% for i in post.file_set.all %}<p class="article-content mt-2 mb-1"><strong>Attachment {{ forloop.counter }}: </strong><a href="{{i.file.url}}" >{{i.file.name}}</a></p>{% endfor %}